# PDFs viewing possibility

Tags: javascript, pdf, web

Is there any application or method to view PDFs as "picture-in-picture"?

I wanted to try this as a means of duping a window focus tracker on a remote proctoring site.

The examination is open-book and since I don't have the prints I'm trying to explore ways to view PDFs without having to change windows or tabs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best way to do so is by using PDF.js as it renders PDF's in HTML5 in your browser. I haven't come across any better solutions.

see: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Comment: ah well i do use it as a chrome extension but i was looking for a way that didn't include having to switch tabs or windows... sort of an application that could display the pdf as "picture-in-picture"

Comment: You can do this with pdf.js; simply get the pdf rendered data from the pdf.js canvas and you can do with it wathever you like. Check out this codpen (not mine): [link](https://codepen.io/akhiltrivedi-the-scripter/pen/bGNPprR)